# When I am logged-in the page doesn't look the same as when I am logged-off

Tags: theming, 8, users

Do I need to include something in the code or in settings.

I have a problem which is that pages don't look the same when I am login or not. Like on photo down. Some help or suggestion?

This is my code. Does I need to add Edit and view bartik?

Whan I change **base theme: stable** with **base theme: bartik** bug is fixed.

```
<main role="main" class="node-main">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <a id="main-content" tabindex="-1"></a>{# link is in html.html.twig #}

        <div class="col-md-8 node-page">
            {{ page.content }}
        </div>{# /.layout-content #}

        <div class="col-md-4 node-aside">
            <aside >
            {% if page.sidebar_first %}
                    {{ page.sidebar_first }}
            {% endif %}
            {% if page.sidebar_second %}
                    {{ page.sidebar_second }}
            {% endif %}
            </aside>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is likely because of the contextual links (edit, view, revisions etc.) that only display when logged in, as such this is likely something that is specific to the implementation of your theme and difficult to help with (especially from only two screenshots!). Can you provide any further details? Have you tried inspecting the HTML when logged in to see what could be causeing the display to break?

Comment: Sorry I forget to add code. I edit my post new..:)

Answer (score 0):

What you see / notice is pretty standard Drupal ... The link like "Add content" is something you typically only want to be shown for logged in user (and maybe even limited to users with roles such as "content editor" (or whatever you'd call it). Also, the small icons in the upper left (above "logo" and "home") are typically also things you only should be able to use if you are logged in.

Should you want to change any of such things (eg: anonymous users should also be able to "add content"), then it's just a matter of finding out which permission it is that actually governs the specific function (such as "add content"), and then indicate in your "permissions" page within admin that is related to it that you want "role" anonymous to have the very same permission.

Comment: Probably I didnt ask question good. I know what is Add content. Problem is that style change when I log in. I fix this by do base theme: bartik and not base theme: stable http://prntscr.com/a3b0hn So i dont know what css or code have bartik what fix this problem and didnt have my code.. :(